# Suppress Makefile output when calling Make

Tags: makefile

I know about the `@command` syntax for suppressing the output of a command. But how to suppress the call of another Makefile?

```
@$(MAKE) -C ./other/
```

The upper example still prints

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/proj/other/'
```

How to suppress this? Invocation of the "main" Makefile by `make 2>&1 /dev/null` (or similar) is no option for me!

Comment: I believe the `--no-print-directory` argument is what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--no-print-directory` argument is what you are looking for here.